# Random Image Generation on Android by tapping on ImageView

Tags: java, android, image, random

I'm pretty new to Android developing and I'm trying to make an app that chooses between 3 images randomly and shows one of them on the phone screen whenever the image is tapped.

The problem is that the image is always the same and instead of changing it disappears and reappears with every tap.

The images names are: w0.png, w1.png and w2.png

```
private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
private ImageView iv;
private int q;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    q = rgenerator.nextInt(2);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("w"+q, "drawable", getPackageName());
    iv.setImageResource(resId);

    iv.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.imageView1)
    {
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("w"+ rgenerator.nextInt(2), "drawable", getPackageName());
        iv.setImageResource(resId);
    }
}
```

This is activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.mandandroid.MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `nextInt(2)` returns 0 or 1. You probably want `nextInt(3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the fact that you use the same instance of `Random()` over the lifetime of your Activity. Java's `Random` is a pseudo random number generator, meaning that you can get the same values multiple times. When you instantiate `rgenerator` it will have the same seed and it will use it to generate your `random` values.

Also you use `.nextInt(int n)` which by definition excludes value `n`, in your case value `2`, meaning that you are left only with values `0` and `1` to be returned. From documentation, it looks like you get almost equal chances to get any value in the interval specified, so in your case you really have equal chances to get a `0` or a `1` because there are only two values.

Because you use `Random` only to get one of the three values I would suggest you create your randomization by using an increment or another simple method within your bounds.

You can read more about Java `Random` class in the official documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt()) and a small example on how to use it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/random_nextint_inc_exc.htm).